Problems with subsetting data in R
I'm trying to calculate group mean for year-skilled groups, but all unskilled values turn to be NAN. There are obs with skilled==1 and skilled==0 every year.
Below are my code:
wage_df <- df %>% 
  filter(!is.na(wage) & !is.na(skilled)) %>% 
  group_by(year) %>% 
  summarise(skilled = mean(wage[skilled == 1]),
            unskilled = mean(wage[skilled == 0]),
            total = sum(wage * wtsupp) / sum(wtsupp))

However, if I do this:
wage_df <- df %>% 
  filter(!is.na(wage) & !is.na(skilled)) %>% 
  group_by(year) %>% 
  summarise(unskilled = mean(wage[skilled == 0]),
            skilled = mean(wage[skilled == 1]),
            total = sum(wage * wtsupp) / sum(wtsupp))

All appear to work well.
I'm wondering why the order affect the result?

Are you able to share a reproducible example of the dataframe?

dplyr's summarise (and mutate) function update columns "on the fly", so you have changed skilled in the first code, but not the second, before you calculate unskilled.
